# "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority" is revoked after updating to Windows 10. How do I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I have a Windows 7 system that I've just updated to Windows 10. After doing so, I found a ton of drivers wouldn't install, and eventually traced the issue to the root certificate "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority" being revoked.

I have no idea why it's revoked, but I've tried the following actions to fix it:

1. Redownloading trusted root certificates from Windows update and reinstalling them. This certificate is still marked as revoked.
2. Exporting this certificate from another working Windows 10 system (which does not list it as revoked), deleting it from this system, and re-importing it using the exported file. It still is listed as revoked.
3. Downloading the Certificate Trust List and revoked certificate list from Windows update and importing that. Still no luck.
4. Disabling driver signing enforcement and trying to install the drivers. The installer still fails in spite of this.

This is driving me crazy. How do I get this certificate working? My system can't function properly without it.

[image: Screenshot of certificate]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Can you provide a screenshot of the revoked certificate for more verbose research?  There are multiple Microsoft Root Certificate Authority certificates, Microsoft has replaced the less secure certificates, and revoked those that have expired or are using a less secure encryption algorithm.  Windows 7 since it has NOT been updated in 3 years likely had one of those certificates that had expired, as to the reason the certificate(s) are not being installed, that(s) the reason for the additional information

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited my post to mention a specific Win 10 version (21H2) and a screenshot. The name of the certificate is "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority" exactly, and is the only one with that exact name. I think this certificate being revoked has something to do with upgrading from Win 7, but note that in my post I mention that on all of my other Win 10 systems it is *not* revoked. Because it's revoked I can't install drivers that were signed with it, and it was valid until May of 2021. So I need some way of making this certificate valid again so I can install these drivers.

Comment: Based on the screenshot that certificate is in the user's trusted Root CA store. Did you move it there? Did you move the same certificate to the system's trusted Root CA store? The error is indicating the certificate cannot be trusted due to a certificate parameter, that certificate, has not actually been revoked (based off that screenshot).

Comment: I am also confused why you believe an expired that certificate has been revoked, based on the information, the certificate is simply not trusted due to a parameter of the certificate itself (which cannot changed). I have the same certificate on my system, "expired or not yet valid", and does not have the parameter error.  Are you connected to an Active Directory domain by chance? I am looking at the certificate manager for the the "local computer" could you provide that information?

Comment: @Ramhound That certificate was already in the user and system's Root CA store. I didn't add it manually. I am not part of an Active Directory domain. Remember that I too have this exact certificate on other Win 10 systems, and it's "expired or not yet valid" on those systems. If I export the certificate from a working system, and then import it on to my nonworking system, the nonworking system still sees it as revoked. So it's not the certificate itself that has a property making it revoked, but something else. (Certificate Revocation List perhaps? I tried resetting that but it didn't help.)

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix for this.  I had a single machine where "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority.cer" was revoked/not trusted, same as your screenshot.  In my case I was trying to install a driver and that was failing with error code 800f0247.

I was able to remove the certs from the bad machine and import from a known good machine.  Here are the steps:

1. On a working machine, Export all certificates from the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store that being with "Microsoft".  I saved each cert as .cer with the display name as the filename.
2. On the problem machine, delete each Trusted Root Certification Authority cert that beings with "Microsoft".
3. Import the certificates using powershell cmdlet Import-Certificate.  I tried importing them manually and that didn't seem to work.  Not sure if it was user error or Import-Certificate is necessary.  Either way, I placed all of the root certs in a folder and then ran the following powershell command to import all certs in that folder with one command: `Get-ChildItem -File | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root`
4. At this point the driver install I was running that was failing due to the "revoked" certificate worked.  Another post I read recommended clearing CRL and OCSP cache (`certutil -urlcache crl delete && certutil -urlcache ocsp delete`) and restarting, but I didn't seem to have to do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).